# How do I disable the beep/bell sound in iTerm2 in macbook?

Tags: mac, terminal, notifications, iterm2, bell

The shell in macbook makes annoying beep/bell/boop sounds.

For the OEM terminal, this answer works on disabling this annoying sounds:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19166539/i-want-to-disable-beep-sound-in-terminal-mac-osx

However, I could not figure out how to do this for `iTerm2`.

I have notifications for iTerm2 disabled in `System Preferences -> Notifications -> iTerm` but that doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

To disable the bell sound in `iTerm2`, do this:

- `iTerm2 -> Preferences -> Profiles`
- Under `Terminal` tab, you will see `Notifications` header. Toggle the `Silence bell` option.

[image]

EDIT: Please note that intuitively you might think that you want the `Silence bell` to be checked, but if it's already checked then unchecking it will resolve your issue. So, basically toggling it seems to be the key.

Comment: Also make sure you disable the notification center "send bell alert" :) SO ANNOYING

Comment: Checking the "Silence bell" option turns off sounds for me, not unchecking it.

Comment: @Ryan for me it was the opposite; I found it weird at first because it's unintuitive to uncheck a `Silence bell` option to silence something. In that case, maybe it's just a toggle; so toggling this checkbox would toggle the behavior from whatever state it's on.

Comment: @rrlamichhane, many thanks to you, man! Do you know how it feels like, when there is no sound when I hit the tab key? The silence, it feels great! Thanks a lot.

Comment: is there a command line settings to configure iterm? don't want to do this on all my macs

Comment: At least with iterm2 3.4.6, checking or unchecking the `Silence bell` checkbox has no effect. My repro is to open a new window and then press what on an Apple Macbook Pro is the [delete] key. The only thing that works is to check `Silence bell` *and* check `Notification Center Alerts` and then click [Filter Alerts] and then uncheck `Send "Bell" alert`. Ridonkulous.

Comment: Confirmed for `3.4.19`:  checking `Silence bell`and unchecking `Send "Bell" alert` *for every single profile* individually `¯\_(ツ)_/¯` will finally silence the goddamn bell.  Ridiclious, Ludicronkulous, with more than a metric ton of asininliousness.

Comment: Would be much nicer to have a single global  `NEVER EVER PRODUCE SOUND` checkbox which is enabled by default.

Answer (score 5):

Got to:

```
iTerm2 -> Preferences -> Profiles
```

Under Terminal tab, you will see Notifications header. Make sure the Silence bell option is **Checked**
[image]